# has_many and belongs_to models rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I need to create 2 models: Authors and Books.

The table Books will contain 4 columns:

- first_author: int #will be populated with an Authors_id
- second_author: int #will be populated with an Authors_id
- third_author: int #will be populated with an Authors_id
- fourth_author: int #will be populated with an Authors_id

I cannot use `has_many :books` as the table Books will not contain a column `Authors_id`.

What type of association do I need between Books and Authors? Or no need to create a relation at all and create a method that fetches Authors_id where necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join table:

`rails g model BookAuthors book_id:references author_id:references`

then in your Book model

`has_many :authors, :through => :BookAuthors`

and in your Author model

`has_many :boooks, :through => :BookAuthors`

You can read more about associations here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html 
They even use the book/author example :)

Comment: Thanks Brad. But then I don't see how this populates the fields `first_author, second_author` etc with the Authors_id.

Comment: I have added a new answer, should do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is tell rails that first_author and second_author etc are all going to be referencing an author. because this is not the usual rails convention, we pass the foreign key to the model association to tell it.

In you Book Model:

```
has_one :first_author, foreign_key: "author_id"
has_one :second_author, foreign_key: "author_id"
has_one :third_author, foreign_key: "author_id"
has_one :fourth_author, foreign_key: "author_id"
```

In your Author Model:

`has many :books`

Comment: with this second answer, is a join table still necessary ?

Comment: I have expanded a little on the answer, hope it helps, please let me know how you get on

Comment: really sorry: in `Class CreateBibliographies` I add `t.references :author_1, foreign_key: true` ?

Comment: or should I just leave `t.integrer :author_1` ?

Comment: if you do t.references :author_1, foreign_key: true it will look for a model name called author_1 which doesn't exist. I think just leave as integer.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll post here what the result's going to be. I will need to also integrate this with the forms.